# script first line _author_="dev" does not show up

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, ide

I am learning Python by watching youtube videos and also through an online course that I bought.  In every video I watch, the first line of each file is: `_author_='dev'`.  For some reason when I start a new file this does not come up.  What does this mean and if it is an issue how do I correct it?

FYI I am using IntelliJ IDEA as an IDE.

Thank you!

Comment: It means they have configured their IDE to include that boilerplate in new Python files they create. If you want it, add it.

Comment: Aside: I recommend [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), part of the official Python documentation. It's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pre-compiled in some IDEs like PyDev but not in IDEA, you can add it manually if you want it. I also recommend you to use PyCharm instead of IDEA for python.

Comment: Thanks Moe, what does it mean though?  What would I gain by adding it?

Comment: its for setting author to whatever name you provide, just like `__version__ `and `__credits__` ..etc its called metadata for the module. You can find more info here: http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-fields.html#module-metadata-variables